# Convert a Byte Array to String in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to convert a byte array to a string in Silverlight, but I get the following compilation error:

'System.Text.Encoding.GetString(byte[])' is inaccessible due to its protection level

This is the method that I'm using:

```
string text = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myByteArray);
```

How else can I achieve this?

Comment: 'UTF8Encoding.UTF8' is not what you would usually use - you would either use Encoding.UTF8 to get the 'normal' UTF8 encoding (which has BOM on) or do 'new UTFEncoding(..)' to ctor your own.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can write:

```
string text = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(yourByteArray, 0, yourByteArray.Length);
```

Silverlight 3 and 4 [only support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3%28VS.95%29.aspx) that override.

Answer (score 2):

```
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myByteArray,0,myByteArray.Length);
```

Works in SL4, don't know about anything earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You May use Inicode encoding also,

```
   String text=(new UnicodeEncoding()).GetString(barray, 0, barry.Length)
```

By this way you are able to get as string from byte[],

vice versa by

```
   Byte[] myarray=(new UnicodeEncoding()).getBytes(Stringexpressin);
```