# System.Text.Encoding is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, encoding, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I am trying to deserialize and serialize JSON in a Lightswitch app, and in that procedure I need to use encoding. The problem is that after build I get this error :

> 'System.Text.Encoding.GetString(byte[])' is inaccessible due to its
>   protection level

and this error also appear after build at  `[Serializable]`  tag

The question is why? The reference `System.Text` is already there and using namespace also...

Comment: May be this is a help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055716/convert-a-byte-array-to-string-in-silverlight

Comment: Ouu how its possible i didnt found this :-( thank you !!!! and what about the [serializabe] prbolem ? i cant that ovveride